# Is SpringLayout a fixed-size layout manager?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, springlayout

I know the following Java Swing layout managers: `FlowLayout`, `BoxLayout`, `BorderLayout`, `GridLayout`, `GroupLayout` (which I avoid using), and `GridBagLayout`.

I call `GridBagLayout` a fixed-size layout manager as it defines rows and columns with fixed size. I would not use it in a responsive application if I want all my panels to be resizable. I would try to combine a few of the other layout managers instead.

Out of curiosity I'm considering adopting a new layout manager, `SpringLayout`, for an app revamp. But after glancing at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/spring.html) I'm under the impression `SpringLayout` is a fixed-size layout manager as well. So, is it? Will it hurt my app's responsiveness?

Comment: `GridBagLayout` scales depending on contents, and `SpringLayout` is all about springs.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline How does `GridBagLayout` scale? It parts from a minimal fixed-size layout I assume.

Comment: `weightx` and `weighty`. (It has a number of gotchas, including going weird if squeezed less the preferred size.)