# Is combining layout managers the way to go in a Java Swing responsive design?

Tags: java, swing, responsive, layout-manager

I have [little experience](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60208498/2241463) with Java Swing. I'd like to ask if my idea of combining layouts to obtain a responsive app is the way to go in order to create a semi-responsive Swing app (*"semi-"* in the sense it should look good given a minimal screen resolution, say 800 x 600 pixels).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's the way to go in standard Java without Libraries.

**Personal Opinion:**

I personally really dislike the LayoutManagers delivered in Swing (apart from the simple Flow and Border Layouts). Therefore I use [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) to do most of the Layout. This avoids having to combine multiple `LayoutManager` to position a single component. The learning curve might be a bit larger than with the simple Layouts, but I still think it's easier than `GridBagLayout` and can do a LOT more.

Once you get it the code will be super clean, as it works with Layout Constraints that (when using String Constraints) kinda is a graphical representation of your Layout Settings.

Here's a guide to get you started: http://www.miglayout.com/QuickStart.pdf

And here you can look up the commands you can use: http://www.miglayout.com/whitepaper.html